# Find the solution of $\displaystyle \frac{\partial^{2}u}{\partial x^2}+\frac{\partial^{2}u}{\partial y^2}=64$

Tags: partial-differential-equations, solution-verification

Let $u(x,y) $ be the solution of $\displaystyle \frac{\partial^{2}u}{\partial x^2}+\frac{\partial^{2}u}{\partial y^2}=64$ in the unit disk $\left \{(x,y)|x^2+y^2<1  \right \}$ and such that $u$ vanishes on the boundary of the disk,Then $\displaystyle u\left ( \frac{1}{4},\frac{1}{\sqrt 2} \right )$

**Solution I tried**-I tried the method $$m^2+1=0$$
$$m^2=-1$$
$$m=\pm i$$
so the C.S is 
$$\phi_1(y+ix)+\phi_2(y-ix)$$

$$\text{and P.I i solved is }32x^2$$

so complete soltuion is  $$\phi_1(y+ix)+\phi_2(y-ix)+32x^2$$

but t seems that this solution will not help me because there is imaginary part in solution,

I also tried solution by taking $u=Ae^{hx+ky}$ in end i get$$h^2=-k^2$$ complete solution is

$$\sum Ae^{hx \pm ihy}+32x^2$$ but i have no idea how can these solution can help me to get desired result

Please Help

Thank you

Comment: Where do the $m$'s come from? As an aside, given that the region of interest is the unit disk, it maybe helpful instead to convert the equation into polar coordinates.

Comment: here i have considered  $D^2=m^2$

Comment: Just more confusion, what is $D$ ??

Comment: equation can be written as $D^2+D'^{2}=0$ for auxiliary equation

Comment: Alternatively, if you know the Green's function for the Laplace equation with Dirichlet conditions on the unit circle, you can just use that.

Comment: i have no idea about Green's function.How can i change this in polar form?

Comment: @TheStudent. In the question you wrote : Then $\displaystyle u\left ( \frac{1}{4},\frac{1}{\sqrt 2} \right )$ . What do you mean ?

Comment: @JJacquelin   First i have to find $u$ then i have to find the value of that function on this point

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Cartesian coordinates $(x,y)\quad :\quad \displaystyle \frac{\partial^{2}u}{\partial x^2}+\frac{\partial^{2}u}{\partial y^2}=64$

Polar coordinates : $(\rho,\theta)\quad : \quad \displaystyle\frac{\partial^{2}u}{\partial \rho^2} +\frac{1}{\rho}\frac{\partial u}{\partial \rho}+\frac{1}{\rho^2}\frac{\partial^2 u}{\partial \theta^2}=64$

The given boundary condition is not sufficient to consider the solutions which might be functions of $\theta$. So we assume that $\frac{\partial u}{\partial \theta}=0$ everywhere.

$$\displaystyle\frac{d^{2}u}{d \rho^2} +\frac{1}{\rho}\frac{d u}{d \rho}=64$$
$$\frac{d u}{d \rho}=c_1\frac{1}{\rho}+32\rho$$

$$u=c_1\ln(\rho)+c_2+16\rho^2$$ 
The condition $u=0$ at $\rho=1$ implies $c_2=-16$.
$$u=c_1\ln(\rho)+16(\rho^2-1)$$
Again the wording of the problem seems ambiguous about the boundary conditions. The most likely it is supposed that $u$ is continuous and finite at $\rho=0$ which implies $c_1=0$.
$$u=16(\rho^2-1)$$
$$u(x,y)=16(x^2+y^2-1)$$
This satisfies the PDE and the condition $u=0$ on the unit circle.

$u(1/4,\: 1/\sqrt{2})=16(\frac{1}{16}+\frac12-1)=-7$

Comment: Thankyou @JJacquellin , but why we considering $\displaystyle \frac{\partial u}{\partial \theta }=0$?

Comment: Because the problem is ill-posed. As wanted, a solution was found. It was not asked to prove if the solution is unique or not.